# KafkaStreams.cleanUp() doesn't remove the correct directory

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka-streams, spring-kafka

I have the following problem, maybe someone can help me with a hint where to look.
my project:
- kafka version 1.1.1, kafka-streams within spring-boot app, provided EmbeddedKafka for integration tests, macosx, jdk 1.8

In my streams config I have:
- 1 global ktable,
- 1 global store and
- 1 state store,
- 1 processor and 1 transformer for global store and
- 1 transformer with punctuation (WALL_CLOCK_TIME) for state store.

I introduced the CleanupConfig to call KafkaStreams.cleanUp() onClose (in my integration tests). This works well with global store, but not with state store which remains undeleted. I turned on logging on kafka StateDirectory and here is what I see.
Before my integration test starts:

```
14:39:58.609 [kstreams-3892e198-bf56-4ac1-bd21-68c580309d4d-GlobalStreamThread] DEBUG o.a.k.s.p.internals.StateDirectory - stream-thread [kstreams-3892e198-bf56-4ac1-bd21-68c580309d4d-GlobalStreamThread] Acquired global state dir lock

14:39:59.153 [kstreams-3892e198-bf56-4ac1-bd21-68c580309d4d-StreamThread-1] DEBUG o.a.k.s.p.internals.StateDirectory - stream-thread [kstreams-3892e198-bf56-4ac1-bd21-68c580309d4d-StreamThread-1] Acquired state dir lock for task 2_0
```

Note that it acquired lock for task 2_0

After the integration test:

```
14:40:07.079 [kstreams-3892e198-bf56-4ac1-bd21-68c580309d4d-GlobalStreamThread] DEBUG o.a.k.s.p.internals.StateDirectory - stream-thread [kstreams-3892e198-bf56-4ac1-bd21-68c580309d4d-GlobalStreamThread] Released global state dir lock

14:40:17.032 [Thread-6] DEBUG o.a.k.s.p.internals.StateDirectory - stream-thread [Thread-6] Acquired state dir lock for task 1_0

14:40:17.032 [Thread-6] INFO  o.a.k.s.p.internals.StateDirectory - stream-thread [Thread-6] Deleting state directory 1_0 for task 1_0 as user calling cleanup.

14:40:17.033 [Thread-6] DEBUG o.a.k.s.p.internals.StateDirectory - stream-thread [Thread-6] Released state dir lock for task 1_0
```

Note that it the delete dir for task 2_0 is not called

After the EmbeddedKafka shutdown, this is the log from kafka streams.

```
20:36:08.004 [Thread-6] DEBUG o.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams - stream-client [kstreams-6e816551-a066-455d-a619-2af0d23663b4] Stopping Streams client with timeoutMillis = 10000 ms.
20:36:08.004 [Thread-6] INFO  o.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams - stream-client [kstreams-6e816551-a066-455d-a619-2af0d23663b4] State transition from RUNNING to PENDING_SHUTDOWN
20:36:08.005 [kafka-streams-close-thread] INFO  o.a.k.s.p.internals.StreamThread - stream-thread [kstreams-6e816551-a066-455d-a619-2af0d23663b4-StreamThread-1] Informed to shut down
20:36:08.005 [kafka-streams-close-thread] INFO  o.a.k.s.p.internals.StreamThread - stream-thread [kstreams-6e816551-a066-455d-a619-2af0d23663b4-StreamThread-1] State transition from RUNNING to PENDING_SHUTDOWN
20:36:08.005 [kafka-streams-close-thread] INFO  o.a.k.s.p.i.GlobalStreamThread - global-stream-thread [kstreams-6e816551-a066-455d-a619-2af0d23663b4-GlobalStreamThread] State transition from RUNNING to PENDING_SHUTDOWN
20:36:08.036 [kstreams-6e816551-a066-455d-a619-2af0d23663b4-GlobalStreamThread] DEBUG o.a.k.s.p.i.GlobalStateManagerImpl - global-stream-thread [kstreams-6e816551-a066-455d-a619-2af0d23663b4-GlobalStreamThread] Flushing all global globalStores registered in the state manager
20:36:08.037 [kstreams-6e816551-a066-455d-a619-2af0d23663b4-GlobalStreamThread] INFO  o.a.k.s.p.i.GlobalStreamThread - global-stream-thread [kstreams-6e816551-a066-455d-a619-2af0d23663b4-GlobalStreamThread] Shutting down
20:36:08.038 [kstreams-6e816551-a066-455d-a619-2af0d23663b4-GlobalStreamThread] DEBUG o.a.k.s.p.i.GlobalStateManagerImpl - global-stream-thread [kstreams-6e816551-a066-455d-a619-2af0d23663b4-GlobalStreamThread] Closing global storage engine doc-metadata-store
20:36:08.039 [kstreams-6e816551-a066-455d-a619-2af0d23663b4-GlobalStreamThread] DEBUG o.a.k.s.p.i.GlobalStateManagerImpl - global-stream-thread [kstreams-6e816551-a066-455d-a619-2af0d23663b4-GlobalStreamThread] Closing global storage engine agent-location-store
20:36:08.040 [kstreams-6e816551-a066-455d-a619-2af0d23663b4-GlobalStreamThread] DEBUG o.a.k.s.p.internals.StateDirectory - stream-thread [kstreams-6e816551-a066-455d-a619-2af0d23663b4-GlobalStreamThread] Released global state dir lock
20:36:08.040 [kstreams-6e816551-a066-455d-a619-2af0d23663b4-GlobalStreamThread] INFO  o.a.k.s.p.i.GlobalStreamThread - global-stream-thread [kstreams-6e816551-a066-455d-a619-2af0d23663b4-GlobalStreamThread] State transition from PENDING_SHUTDOWN to DEAD
20:36:08.040 [kstreams-6e816551-a066-455d-a619-2af0d23663b4-GlobalStreamThread] INFO  o.a.k.s.p.i.GlobalStreamThread - global-stream-thread [kstreams-6e816551-a066-455d-a619-2af0d23663b4-GlobalStreamThread] Shutdown complete
20:36:18.010 [Thread-6] DEBUG o.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams - stream-client [kstreams-6e816551-a066-455d-a619-2af0d23663b4] Cannot transit to NOT_RUNNING within 10000ms
20:36:18.010 [Thread-6] INFO  o.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams - stream-client [kstreams-6e816551-a066-455d-a619-2af0d23663b4] Streams client cannot stop completely within the timeout
20:36:18.011 [Thread-6] DEBUG o.a.k.s.p.internals.StateDirectory - stream-thread [Thread-6] Acquired state dir lock for task 1_0
20:36:18.012 [Thread-6] INFO  o.a.k.s.p.internals.StateDirectory - stream-thread [Thread-6] Deleting state directory 1_0 for task 1_0 as user calling cleanup.
20:36:18.012 [Thread-6] DEBUG o.a.k.s.p.internals.StateDirectory - stream-thread [Thread-6] Released state dir lock for task 1_0
```

What could possibly go wrong here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can it be, that your application is not fully stopped and some locks are not released yet?

Comment: Edited the original post with kafka streams log after EmbeddedKafka is shutdown (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/blob/2.1.x/spring-kafka-test/src/main/java/org/springframework/kafka/test/rule/KafkaEmbedded.java)

Comment: Seem, it does cleanly shut down: `20:36:18.010 [Thread-6] DEBUG o.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams - stream-client [kstreams-6e816551-a066-455d-a619-2af0d23663b4] Cannot transit to NOT_RUNNING within 10000ms`

Comment: EmbeddedKafka calls KafkaServer.shutdown()
    `if (kafkaServer.brokerState().currentState() != (NotRunning.state())) {
    kafkaServer.shutdown();
    kafkaServer.awaitShutdown();
    }`

Comment: It's not about stopping the embedded broker -- it's about stopping `KafkaStreams` client properly.

Comment: Yes, the class that starts and stops KafkaStreams is in spring-kafka library:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/blob/master/spring-kafka/src/main/java/org/springframework/kafka/config/StreamsBuilderFactoryBean.java
Do you maybe see anything wrong there?

Comment: Not in particular. It calls close() https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/blob/master/spring-kafka/src/main/java/org/springframework/kafka/config/StreamsBuilderFactoryBean.java#L314 -- it can also call cleanup() for you if you configure it accordingly -- you can also set the timeout for close() -- maybe you need to increase it.